# Using Google Map Fragment in onCreateView() with Tabs

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have my `FragmentActivity` extends `ActionBar.TabListener` with two tabs.

In my first tab I'm trying to display `GoogleMap`.

How can I do it in my `onCreateView()` method? This is my code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        this.ctx = container.getContext();

        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This code get me an errore on `getMap()`:

> The method getMap() is undefined for the type MapFragment

This is my XML layout fragment_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15320/google-maps-actionbar-tabs

Comment: Change your class name `MapFragment` to be else

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the XML of your `MapFragment`?

Comment: Also is your `Fragment` from `android.support.v4`?

Comment: Yes my `Fragment` is from `android.support.v4`

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet you upgrade your GooglePlayServices library.

> **public final GoogleMap getMap()**
>
> This method is deprecated.
>
> Use getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) instead. The callback method provides you with a GoogleMap instance guaranteed to be non-null and ready to be used.

You now need to use [getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) instead of `getMap()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use getMapAsync.. I'll text you if it help me!

Comment: I'm following Google documentation [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map] (my class extends Fragment not FragmentActivity because it's one tab of my activity) but it gives me an error on `getMapAsync`. How can I do?

Comment: Error you say? My crystal ball I forgot. The error to me you should describe ^^

Comment: `The method getMapAsync(Context) is undefined for the type MapFragment`

Comment: I need more information, see the comments on your question.